# Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Configuration.Settings cannot find Newtonsoft.Json package

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have a `.NET Core 2.2` project setup in Azure DevOps that uses a CI pipeline to build, and recently, after updating the `Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build` NuGet package to version `2.1.175` the CI pipeline has been throwing the following exception every time I try and run it:

`System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Cache.WebRequestHandler' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Configuration.Settings' threw an exception. --->  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621)`

[image]

I've tried installing `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package in the project but am still getting this error.

Is there something I need to be adding to the pipeline, or something that I need added to the project itself to resolve this?